# Необходима функция, которая определяет четность и нечетность

Tags: javascript

Нужна функция, принимающая объект с полем. И возвращающая 0, есои длина этого полячетная и 1, если длина нечетная. 
Думал использовать %, но ничего умней в голову не пришло.

Answer (score 2):

```
function parity(obj) { 
  return obj.field.length % 2
}
```

Comment: название функции, естественно, любое и вместо field название нужного поля

Comment: Или `parity(obj, field) { return obj[ field ].length % 2 }`

Answer (score 1):

```
var a = 2;
if ( a & 1 ) {
    alert( "нечетно" );
} else {
    alert( "четно" );
}
```

Comment: Для длины пойдёт, а вообще есть 2 нюанса.

Answer (score 0):

```
function parity(obj) { 
  return +(obj.field.length % 2)
}
```

Comment: Эта, плюсик зачем?